# How to resolve resource-root path for jboss-deployment-structure inside the docker

Tags: java, docker, jboss, wildfly

I have a jar which can't be copied to ear while generating docker-image. Also, I can't add the jars as modules because of some dependency issue.
So, I have added below resource-root in my jboss-deployment-structure file(To make it same as copying the jar in the EAR's lib directory).

false

```
<!-- This corresponds to the top level deployment. For a war this is the war's module, for an ear -->
<!-- This is the top level ear module, which contains all the classes in the EAR's lib folder     -->
<deployment>

    <!-- exclude-subsystem prevents a subsystems deployment unit processors running on a deployment -->
    <!-- which gives basically the same effect as removing the subsystem, but it only affects single deployment -->
    <exclude-subsystems>
        <subsystem name="jpa"/>
    </exclude-subsystems>

    <dependencies>
        <module name="org.abc" services="import"/>
        <module name="org.abcde.zye" optional="true"/>
    </dependencies>
    <resources>
    <!-- These add additional classes to the module. In this case it is the same as including the jar in the EAR's lib directory -->
        <resource-root path="/../../../standalone/outsideEar/outside-abc.jar"/>
    </resources>
</deployment>
<sub-deployment name="abc-abc.war">
    <dependencies>
        <module name="org.abcde.zye" optional="true"/>
    </dependencies>
</sub-deployment>
<sub-deployment name="abc-ejb.jar">
    <dependencies>
        <module name="org.abcde.zye" optional="true"/>
    </dependencies>
</sub-deployment>
```

**My Ear Structure:**

```
my-ear.ear
   |- lib
   |- abc-abc.war
   |- abc-ejb.jar
   |- META-INF
        |- application.xml
        |- jboss-app.xml
        |- jboss-deployment-structure.xml
        |- maven
             |- pom.properties
             |- pom.xml
```

When **I deploy this ear to wildfly-15.0.1.Final server outside the docker it works fine**. 
Path for resource-root is resolved, outside-abc.jar is copied to the below tmp folder (which is generated dynamically on server start) and I am able to perform operation by using classes of outside-abc.jar.
**wildfly-15.0.1.Final\standalone\tmp\vfs\deployment\deploymentdc506469ec651715**

**wildfly-15.0.1.Final structure:**

```
wildfly-15.0.1.Final
  |- bin
  |- domain
  |- modules
  |- standalone
       |- outsideEar
          <!-- This path is resolved with resource-root path="/../../../standalone/outsideEar/outside-abc.jar" -->
           |- outside-abc.jar
       |- configuration
       |- data
       |- deployments
            |- my-ear.ear
       |- lib
       |- log
       |- tmp
  |-jboss-modules.jar
```

One More case which works fine: If I use below resource-root then my jar should be inside bin folder as wildfly-15.0.1.Final/bin/outsideEar/outside-abc.jar
`<resource-root path="../../outsideEar/outside-abc.jar"/>`

**Docker configuration:**

If I use **same above structure, build docker image and start container for the image**. It is **not able to identify the jar file and do not copy it to 
wildfly-15.0.1.Final\standalone\tmp\vfs\deployment\deploymentdc506469ec651715** folder which eventually **causes ClassNotFoundException** while performing operations.
I have **verified that outside-abc.jar is properly copied to the mounted docker** directory(Already added configuration in docker-compose file).

I have been further inside of this and found that a attribute `use-physical-code-source="true"` can be set for resource-root to resolve the path using physical source code location.

When `use-physical-code-source="true"` : It reads from physical location. I am not getting what is the actual physical location inside the docker. I think it is deployments folder or deployments/my-ear.ear/META-INF.

When `use-physical-code-source="false"(default is false)` : It reads from vfs directory(Inside temp).

I tried many different paths to make it work but, there was no luck.

**Possible cases I tried:**

```
<resource-root path="./../../../../../../../../outsideEar/outside-abc.jar" use-physical-code-source="true"/>
            <resource-root path="./../../../../../../../../outsideEar/outside-abc.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="./../../../../../../../../../standalone/outsideEar/outside-abc.jar" use-physical-code-source="true"/>
            <resource-root path="./../../../../../../../../../standalone/outsideEar/outside-abc.jar"/>

            <resource-root path="./../../../../../../../outsideEar/outside-abc.jar" use-physical-code-source="true"/>
            <resource-root path="./../../../../../../../outsideEar/outside-abc.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="./../../../../../../../../standalone/outsideEar/outside-abc.jar" use-physical-code-source="true"/>
            <resource-root path="./../../../../../../../../standalone/outsideEar/outside-abc.jar"/>

            <resource-root path="./../../../../../../outsideEar/outside-abc.jar" use-physical-code-source="true"/>
            <resource-root path="./../../../../../../outsideEar/outside-abc.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="./../../../../../../../standalone/outsideEar/outside-abc.jar" use-physical-code-source="true"/>
            <resource-root path="./../../../../../../../standalone/outsideEar/outside-abc.jar"/>

            <resource-root path="./../../../../../outsideEar/outside-abc.jar" use-physical-code-source="true"/>
            <resource-root path="./../../../../../outsideEar/outside-abc.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="./../../../../../../standalone/outsideEar/outside-abc.jar" use-physical-code-source="true"/>
            <resource-root path="./../../../../../../standalone/outsideEar/outside-abc.jar"/>

            <resource-root path="./../../../../outsideEar/outside-abc.jar" use-physical-code-source="true"/>
            <resource-root path="./../../../../outsideEar/outside-abc.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="./../../../../../standalone/outsideEar/outside-abc.jar" use-physical-code-source="true"/>
            <resource-root path="./../../../../../standalone/outsideEar/outside-abc.jar"/>

            <resource-root path="./../../../outsideEar/outside-abc.jar" use-physical-code-source="true"/>
            <resource-root path="./../../../outsideEar/outside-abc.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="./../../../../standalone/outsideEar/outside-abc.jar" use-physical-code-source="true"/>
            <resource-root path="./../../../../standalone/outsideEar/outside-abc.jar"/>

            <resource-root path="./../../outsideEar/outside-abc.jar" use-physical-code-source="true"/>
            <resource-root path="./../../outsideEar/outside-abc.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="./../../../standalone/outsideEar/outside-abc.jar" use-physical-code-source="true"/>
            <resource-root path="./../../../standalone/outsideEar/outside-abc.jar"/>

            <resource-root path="./../outsideEar/outside-abc.jar" use-physical-code-source="true"/>
            <resource-root path="./../outsideEar/outside-abc.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="./../../standalone/outsideEar/outside-abc.jar" use-physical-code-source="true"/>
            <resource-root path="./../../standalone/outsideEar/outside-abc.jar"/>

            <resource-root path="./outsideEar/outside-abc.jar" use-physical-code-source="true"/>
            <resource-root path="./outsideEar/outside-abc.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="./../standalone/outsideEar/outside-abc.jar" use-physical-code-source="true"/>
            <resource-root path="./../standalone/outsideEar/outside-abc.jar"/>

            <resource-root path="./standalone/outsideEar/outside-abc.jar" use-physical-code-source="true"/>
            <resource-root path="./standalone/outsideEar/outside-abc.jar"/>
```

For above cases, **I have mounted jars inside both bin and standalone folders** as bin/outsideEar/outside-abc.jar and standalone/outsideEar/outside-abc.jar. So, I **confirm jar is available to the docker wildlfy** server.

**Requirement summary:**

- How is resource-root path resolved(inside and outside docker) when
  use-physical-code-source="true" and use-physical-code-source="false"?
- Is there any way to pass only directory name for resource root so that
  all the jars under that directory can be copied to tmp/deployment. If
  not possible, then is there any  way which can be applied to pass jar
  name dynamically to the jboss-deployment-structure.xml using either properties file or environment variable so that at container start-up jar can be copied to the temp/deployment.

Any assistance you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: This seems like a weird use-case. Is there a reason the JAR can't just be added to the EAR?

Comment: Not a full answer but use-physical-code-source is not for what you are trying to do.  It's actually to change the behavior of the virtual file system in use in Wildfly to make the jar available from a physical path instead of a virtual location when calling things like *.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().  With use-physical-code-source the jar in the war will be extracted to the temp directory, or exploded, and getCodeSource will resolve to that exploded jar.  Without use-physical-code-source it will resolve to a virtual path.